# using LiveCard to display camera preview _and_ custom SurfaceView on Google Glass?

Tags: android, camera, surfaceview, google-glass

I'm trying to do camera recording and drawings on top on Google Glass, using a LiveCard.

in a regular activity, this would be achieved by using a FrameLayout, with a SurfaceView for the camera preview 'in the back', and another View in front of it used for drawing.

but using a LiveCard, if one needs subsecond updates, one has to use the LiveCard itself as a Surface. according to the documentation: https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/com/google/android/glass/timeline/LiveCard

> If your application requires more frequent updates (several times per
>   second) or rendering more elaborate graphics than the standard widgets
>   support, enable direct rendering and add a SurfaceHolder.Callback to
>   the card's surface.
>
> ```
>  LiveCard liveCard; // initialized elsewhere
>  liveCard.setDirectRenderingEnabled(true);
>  liveCard.getSurfaceHolder().addCallback(callback);   You can then draw directly on the surface inside a background thread or in response
> ```
>
> to external events (for example, sensor or location updates). Use the
>   surfaceCreated and surfaceDestroyed methods to start and stop your
>   rendering logic when the card is displayed or hidden.

now I can either draw my on stuff on this Surface, or I can give this to the MediaRecorder as the camera preview service, but can't do both, as it will fail with an error

I wonder if anyone has ideas on how to make this work still?

the way I'd draw into the LiveCard myself is to 'manually' lock the canvas, and call FrameLayout.draw(canvas); one option would be to have a layout that contains two SurfaceViews - one for the camera preview, and one for my own drawings, and use the same approach. but, even if I define such a layout in XML, I can't get the SurfaceViews created (e.g. the appropriate SurfaceView callbacks are never called, and any attempt of drawing on them results in failure)